# Google Earth crashes with R6025 VC++ Run time Error

Tags: windows, google-earth

I have Windows 7 64 bit and Google Earth 6.2.2. Off lately Google Earth randomly crashes with VC++ Run Time Error R6025 (Message - R6025 Pure Virtual Function Call)

Searching the internet does not yield meaningful results, most of the results state the cause of this as some corruption in Windows or its registry and ask me to download third party PC Optimization tools!

Does anyone know what really causes this error and is there a fix. I tried reinstalling Google Earth but that did not help. I don't have any restore points to revert to any previous system state.

Thanks

Comment: Did you install/update something before it started crashing?

Comment: No apps were installed recently and no updates too.

Comment: You could try reinstalling the .NET framework.For that press the WINDOWS key on your keyboard, enter "windows feature", click on "Turn Windows features on or off", uncheck everything with ".NET Framework" in it's name, click "OK", click on "Close" and open the window again, recheck the boxes you unchecked, click "OK", click on "Download files from Windows Update", wait, click on "Close" and restart windows.